# How to send push notification to more than 10000 users using firebase in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I have more than 10k user, and I have an array of token, how can I send to all of user ? I tried to chunk array 1000 user each time, push 1000 user to a Topic, and remove the user from a topic ( in a loop). But it is running false. Does anyone meet this case? thank you!
Sample code:

```
let registrationTokens =[
token1,
token2,...
token10000
]
let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push(
        admin
            .messaging()
            .subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic) // subscrible topic 
            .then(function(response) {
                // send message to topic
                admin
                    .messaging()
                    .send(message)
                    .then(response => {
                        // remove user from topic 
                        admin
                            .messaging()
                            .unsubscribeFromTopic(registrationTokens, topic);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
                console.log(error);
                return res.send(error);
            })
    );
}

Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 1):

Topics are meant for a use-case where your user subscribes to receive messages about a certain... topic. What you have here does not seem like a good usage of topics.

Since you already have the device tokens of the instance you want to send the message to:

1. You can call the API to [send a message to a specific device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices) 10.000 times.
2. Alternatively, you can use the [legacy HTTP API to send downstream messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) to 1000 devices at a time, using the `registration_ids` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this way  : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm
send a multicast message

Answer (score 1):

You can send push notification to a list containing up to 500 registration tokens, using 'sendMulticast' on Firebase Admin SDK package check firebase [docucumentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#node.js_1) for more information.